# how to configure system property  in procfile?

Tags: java, heroku, jvm

the following is the Procfile content but does not seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dtest=123"
    export JAVA_OPTS
    web:    java $JAVA_OPTS -jar maple/web/target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT maple/web/target/*.war
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `-Dtest=123` directly in the Procfile statement like:

```
web:    java $JAVA_OPTS -Dtest=123 -jar maple/web/target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT maple/web/target/*.war
```

Comment: I should've been more clear about it. I actually just want to set a system property not a jvm option.

Comment: Environment variables are set with `heroku config:add FOO=bar`.  Is that what you are looking for?